# python fuzzywuzzy ratio different output on server as on local machine

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I'm using fuzzywuzzy to calculate the similarity between two strings. for example:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
fuzz.ratio('12aefadfaeaffdafafa3','124afdefadaefadfaad')
>>> 56
```

This is embedded into some code that I can run on my webserver (amazon lightsail running bitnami instance) and on my local machine (2012 MB pro running pycharm). The result of the example input above is 56 on my local machine, but returns 72 on my server. I'm running the same version of fuzzywuzzy on both (0.17.0). Initially I thought this could be happening because my local machine runs python 3.6 and my server runs python 2.7 but if I run the same example in python 2.7 on my local machine, the result is still 56.

This difference occurs for many examples I tried, especially when the input strings get a bit long. Though for simple comparisons, the results are sometimes the same as well. I can't see any clear pattern though.

I'm relatively new to python, and I don't really know what could be causing this difference, or how I can debug this further. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar challenge when I had python-Levenshtein installed on my local, while it failed build on the webserver.

Make sure you have python3-dev, build-essential, lib-python3-dev and python3-setuptools before installing python-Levenshtein